# How do telegram bot send poll to the group everyday?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I am using telegram-bot-sdk package in laravel! I have created the bot! Only group members can vote in the poll. The bot can send a poll every day at the same time. Please help me!

web.php

```
 Route::post('/webhook', function () {
     $updates = Telegram::getWebhookUpdate();
 Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
 Telegram::sendPoll([
         'chat_id' => $updates->getMessage()->getChat()->getId(),
          'question' => 'Choose one answer!',
          'options' => ['1','2','3']
      ]);
 });
```